# Reshaping from wide to long with multiple columns and years as row values

Tags: r, reshape

I have a messy dataset that has several columns with same colnames and Year variables inside rows. It looks like this:

```
Forecaster                   Real_GDP         Real_GDP   Unemployment       Unemployment   Country 

NA                        Variation in %         NA      % of active pop.      NA         USA
Individual Forecasts           2022             2023        2022               2023       USA
Forecaster_1                    3.3              4.1        1.3                1.6        USA 
Forecaster_2                    2.5              3.9        0.9                1.3        USA
```

I need to transform it from wide to long, add new Unit column and make it look like this:

```
Forecaster       Unit             Indicator     2022    2023  Country

Forecaster_1     Variation in %   Real_GDP      3.3     4.1   USA
Forecaster_2     Variation in %   Real_GDP      2.5     3.9   USA
Forecaster_1     % of active pop. Unemployment  1.3     1.6   USA
Forecaster_2     % of active pop. Unemployment  0.9     1.3   USA
```

I tried using pivot_longer function, but cannot grasp my head around further moves.

For dataframe reproducability, here is the sample code:

```
test2 <- data.frame(Forecaster=c(NA,"Individual Forecasts", "Forecaster_1", "Forecaster_2"),
                   Real_GDP=c("Variation in %", "2022", 3.3, 2.5),
                   Real_GDP=c(NA, "2023", 4.1, 3.9),
                   Unemployment=c("% of active pop.", "2022", 1.3, 0.9),
                   Unemployment=c(NA, "2023", 1.6, 1.3),
                   Country=c("USA","USA", "USA", "USA"))
colnames(test2) <- c("Forecaster", "Real_GDP", "Real_GDP", "Unemployment", "Unemployment", "Country")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first do some cleaning so that the first few rows don't column names or missing values - you could do this with `dplyr::rename()` and then `dplyr::slice(-...)` to remove the first few rows, that don't contain any observations. At that point you have a dataset in wide format and it's easier to pivot it longer.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test2 |>
        as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique") |> 
        rename(GDP_2022 = `Real_GDP...2`,
               GDP_2023 = `Real_GDP...3`,
               unemployment_2022 = `Unemployment...4`,
               unemployment_2023 = `Unemployment...5`
               ) |> 
        slice(-c(1, 2)) |> 
        pivot_longer(GDP_2022:unemployment_2023,
                     names_to = c("indicator", ".value"),
                     names_sep = "_")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Forecaster   Country indicator    `2022` `2023`
  <chr>        <chr>   <chr>        <chr>  <chr> 
1 Forecaster_1 USA     GDP          3.3    4.1   
2 Forecaster_1 USA     unemployment 1.3    1.6   
3 Forecaster_2 USA     GDP          2.5    3.9   
4 Forecaster_2 USA     unemployment 0.9    1.3
```

(Please note that this is still messy data - the `2022` column contains data of different types. You could instead have a column for "GDP" and one for "unemployment" and then a column for "year").

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Output looks nice, but the Unit column is missing. Is it possible to add it?

Comment: Sure, that can be done with a `case_when` call within `mutate`.

Comment: To make it fully tidy, I suggest making a column "year" and a column "number" with the numbers currently being in columns "2022" and "2023". This could be done by a second pivot_longer() or by modifying the first pivot_longer().

Comment: @maRvin, yes, but I think that would make the data less usable. Such a `number` column would be meaningless - a value would be in a completely different unit according to whether they refer to GDP or unemployment. If I wanted to plot the unemployment distribution according to year, I would need to first filter the indicator == unemploymnet.

Comment: @Andrea M I disagree, as this _problem_ already occurs in the columns "2022" and "2023", as the numbers refer to either "GDP" or "Unemployment". This makes the filter step necessary already now. However, the filter step does not represent a disadvantage in my eyes.